# jquery for wp-ui tabs all closed by default

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui-tabs

Hello and thank you for any solutions or advice I may receive

I am not a programmers and know very little about js
I have been busy  fixing problems caused by the recent wordpress update to 3.5 then 3.5.1
i had a problem with wp ui  which seems to have a problem with the new js used by 3.5.1 
the author of the plug-in  seems to have disappeared  and has not been active for over 5 months

After a lot of testing /trial and error  i have the plug-in working  but can't use the 'JQuery ui themes'  only the 'Css 3 styles work '

i have it working now with a lot of changes

i have altered  some of the css files to suit my colour scheme
the files are :-

1. wpui-red
2. wpui-green
3. wpui-quark
4. wpui-safle

the first 3 give the output on the [Degrees](http://www.pgracglasgow.co.uk/degrees) page

the last 1 is on a [test page](http://www.pgracglasgow.co.uk/test%20page)

i have styled this as tabs to show as buttons  and  they work correctly

my problem is with a piece of code i entered into a file tabs.js

in the following path  \wp-ui\js\select\tabs.js

the code i entered is

"    `options.selected = -1;`        "

after  line 133

this code is altered from 
 a script in the wp-ui forums

```
"<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {  jQuery('.ui-tabs').tabs({ collapsible : true, selected : -1  });
</script>"
```

This code is to make all tabs closed by default

i have this installed on a localhost with all the same settings and plug-ins activated 
and it works fine with all tabs closed by default

but on the live site it does not seen to work

i am getting better as css i think   but no nothing about js

i tryed to run the script from the weaver theme header section that has a section for inserting scripts  but it did not work there either on live site or localhost

could anyone point me in the right direction  as i dont think the tabs.js file is loading on the live site  the reason. I wish to us closed tabs  because the wp-ui dialog is not working and i used this to put important news at the top of all pages with a widget and plan to use the tabs to do this

and is the css i entered ok or is it causing a conflict with others as i had to use a lot of !important to override settings to get the desired effect

Any help or suggestions you can give would be great

Comment: Visited the website. I see an error: SyntaxError: missing } after function body
...split=host_splitted.pop()}domain=host_split+"."+domain;var lnklocal_mask="^https...

Comment: sorry still learning could you explain how to find the error and fix it please

Answer (score 0):

Just change selected for active with false

```
.tabs({ collapsible : true, active: false  });`
```